# How to write SQLite Query

Tags: android-sqlite

I want to write this Query in my android program

Select root
From temp2
where sourec='lee' and destination='jhon'

I have tried something like this

```
Cursor c=db.rawQuery("select root from Temp2 where  sourec='" + so + "' and destination='" + de + "'",null);

                   c.moveToFirst();
                   while(!c.isAfterLast())
                   {
                   Toast.makeText(HandelDatbase.this,c.getString(0),1000).show();
                   c.moveToNext();
                   }
                   c.close();
               }
```

But didn't got the answer Please Help me...

Comment: Are you sure that the name of column in your database is 'sourec' and NOT 'source'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use this (its preferred to the raw query):

```
Cursor cursor = db.query("Temp2", new String[]{root}, "source= ? and destination = ?", new String[] {so, de}, null, null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
 while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
     Toast.makeText(HandelDatbase.this, cursor.getString(0), 1000).show();
     cursor.moveToNext();
 }
 cursor.close();
```

And maybe, its `source` and not `sourec`.